# Exception while trying to get context of a canvas in windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, canvas, windows-8, html5-canvas

I am just installed vs 2012 on windows 8 and create a sample javascript app for windows 8 now when I try to run following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>App1</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- App1 references -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
      var c = $("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 175, 50);
      grd.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
      grd.addColorStop(1, "#00FF00");
      ctx.fillStyle = grd;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="url" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200">
        Your browser doesn't support canvas
    </canvas>
</form>
```

its giving the following exception

```
Unhandled exception at line 19, column 11 in ms-appx://ce20ab64-b644-451a-a60f-cafdc7afb4f9/default.html

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var c = $("myCanvas");
```

to

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

and then

```
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

You could use jQuery to get the element with $('#myCanvas').get(0) to get access to the actual HTML element object. The standard docuemnt api works just as well here though.

http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Update:

Wrap code in document ready with

```
$(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Comment: Wrap all your JS code in $(function(){ ...code here }); what is happening is the DOM is not ready when your JS code is being executed.

Comment: OR you can put your js code (the whole script tag with your Javascript in it) to the bottom of the body below your html and that will work as well.

Comment: Accept the answer so other people will know as well

Comment: What comes back when you log the result of $("mycanvas")? Is it even retrieving what you think it should?

Comment: He could also use WinJS.Utilties.ready().then(function() { /* do work */ });

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
var c = $("myCanvas");
```

to

```
var c = $("#myCanvas");
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.  I also highly recommend taking a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, using that link as a reference can greatly help the visibility and clarity of your answer.